# Gaussian integer cardinality

Tags: gaussian-integers

I would like to what cardinal number the group of Gaussian integer $\Bbb Z[i]$ when $i^2=-1$, is similar to?
Is it $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Do you know how to find the cardinality of $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: or of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$?

Comment: They are infinite groups

Comment: so is $\mathbb Z[i]$; thought you were asking if it's countable

Comment: So which one is it???

Answer (score 0):

We know that the cartesian product of numerable sets is numerable. In this case we can visualize the elements of your group as the result of the cartesian product Z x Z. So we have a numerable set. As you said it is the same cardinality of the integers.